# Get unique records from huge json

Tags: json, python-3.x, for-loop

I have a input JSON it may have 50K data and I need to get unique key values from JSON.

Sample JSON :

```
  [
  {
    "updated_data": {
      "last_interaction": "2022-06-20 06:55:55.652434",
      "following_status": "followed",
      "session_id": 123,
      "type":"insert",
      "job_name": "blogger-following",
      "target": "name2",
      "liked": 1,
      "watched": 7,
      "commented": 0,
      "followed": False,
      "unfollowed": False,
      "scraped": False,
      "pm_sent": False
    }
  },
  {
    "updated_data": {
      "last_interaction": "2022-06-20 06:55:55.652434",
      "type":"insert",
      "following_status": "followed",
      "session_id": 3456,
      "job_name": "blogger-following",
      "target": "name3",
      "liked": 67,
      "watched": 78,
      "commented": 0,
      "followed": False,
      "unfollowed": False,
      "scraped": False,
      "pm_sent": False
    }
  },
  {
    "updated_data": {
      "last_interaction": "2022-06-20 06:55:55.652434",
      "following_status": "followed",
      "session_id": 6789,
      "type":"insert",
      "job_name": "blogger-following",
      "target": "name4",
      "liked": 210,
      "watched": 77,
      "commented": 0,
      "followed": False,
      "unfollowed": False,
      "scraped": False,
      "pm_sent": False
    }
  },
  {
    "updated_data": {
      "last_interaction": "2022-06-20 06:55:55.652434",
      "following_status": "followed",
      "session_id": 123,
      "type":"update",
      "job_name": "blogger-following",
      "target": "name5",
      "liked": 21,
      "watched": 790,
      "commented": 0,
      "followed": False,
      "unfollowed": False,
      "scraped": False,
      "pm_sent": False
    }
  },
  {
    "updated_data": {
      "last_interaction": "2022-06-20 06:55:55.652434",
      "following_status": "not followed",
      "session_id": 123456789,
      "type":"update",
      "job_name": "blogger-following",
      "target": "name6",
      "liked": 81,
      "watched": 7,
      "commented": 0,
      "followed": False,
      "unfollowed": False,
      "scraped": False,
      "pm_sent": False
    }
  },
  {
    "updated_data": {
      "last_interaction": "2023-06-20 06:55:55.652434",
      "following_status": "followed",
      "session_id": 123,
      "type":"update",
      "job_name": "blogger-following",
      "target": "name5",
      "liked": 21,
      "watched": 790,
      "commented": 0,
      "followed": False,
      "unfollowed": False,
      "scraped": False,
      "pm_sent": False
    }
  }
]
```

Here in the above input JSON session_id is the one which i need to check and get unique session_id json. If we see the difference for "session_id":"abc1" we have two. I need to take only one by checking "type" if two have same session Id's, condition is - need to check type should be "update" and pick the type "update" one and ignore "insert".

If i get more than two same session Id's, then i need to check type should be "update" and latest "last_interaction"

output should be:

```
    [

  {
    "updated_data": {
      "last_interaction": "2022-06-20 06:55:55.652434",
      "type":"insert",
      "following_status": "followed",
      "session_id": 3456,
      "job_name": "blogger-following",
      "target": "name3",
      "liked": 67,
      "watched": 78,
      "commented": 0,
      "followed": false,
      "unfollowed": false,
      "scraped": false,
      "pm_sent": false
    }
  },
  {
    "updated_data": {
      "last_interaction": "2022-06-20 06:55:55.652434",
      "following_status": "followed",
      "session_id": 6789,
      "type":"insert",
      "job_name": "blogger-following",
      "target": "name4",
      "liked": 210,
      "watched": 77,
      "commented": 0,
      "followed": false,
      "unfollowed": false,
      "scraped": false,
      "pm_sent": false
    }
  },
  {
    "updated_data": {
      "last_interaction": "2022-06-20 06:55:55.652434",
      "following_status": "followed",
      "session_id": 123,
      "type":"update",
      "job_name": "blogger-following",
      "target": "name5",
      "liked": 21,
      "watched": 790,
      "commented": 0,
      "followed": false,
      "unfollowed": false,
      "scraped": false,
      "pm_sent": false
    }
  },
  {
    "updated_data": {
      "last_interaction": "2022-06-20 06:55:55.652434",
      "following_status": "not followed",
      "session_id": 123456789,
      "type":"update",
      "job_name": "blogger-following",
      "target": "name6",
      "liked": 81,
      "watched": 7,
      "commented": 0,
      "followed": false,
      "unfollowed": false,
      "scraped": false,
      "pm_sent": false
    }
  }
]
```

I tried this below code,

```
import json

with open("data.json", "r") as f_in:
    data = json.load(f_in)

values = [];
uniqueNames = [];
for i in data[0]['updated_data']:
    if(i["session_id"] not in uniqueNames):
         uniqueNames.append(i["session_id"]);
         values.append(i)
```

But, Not working as expected. Please provide your expertise to achieve in a efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've understood your question right. This example will load the data from the json file, sort it according `session_id` (with entries that have `type == "update"` first). Then group the data according `session_id` and get first element from each group:

```py
import json
from itertools import groupby


with open("your_data.json", "r") as f_in:
    data = json.load(f_in)

out = []
for _, g in groupby(
    sorted(
        data,
        key=lambda d: (
            d["updated_data"]["session_id"],
            d["updated_data"]["last_interaction"],
            d["updated_data"]["type"] == "update",
        ),
        reverse=True,
    ),
    lambda d: d["updated_data"]["session_id"],
):
    out.append(next(g))

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[
    {
        "updated_data": {
            "last_interaction": "2022-06-20 06:55:55.652434",
            "following_status": "not followed",
            "session_id": 123456789,
            "type": "update",
            "job_name": "blogger-following",
            "target": "name6",
            "liked": 81,
            "watched": 7,
            "commented": 0,
            "followed": False,
            "unfollowed": False,
            "scraped": False,
            "pm_sent": False,
        }
    },
    {
        "updated_data": {
            "last_interaction": "2022-06-20 06:55:55.652434",
            "following_status": "followed",
            "session_id": 6789,
            "type": "insert",
            "job_name": "blogger-following",
            "target": "name4",
            "liked": 210,
            "watched": 77,
            "commented": 0,
            "followed": False,
            "unfollowed": False,
            "scraped": False,
            "pm_sent": False,
        }
    },
    {
        "updated_data": {
            "last_interaction": "2022-06-20 06:55:55.652434",
            "type": "insert",
            "following_status": "followed",
            "session_id": 3456,
            "job_name": "blogger-following",
            "target": "name3",
            "liked": 67,
            "watched": 78,
            "commented": 0,
            "followed": False,
            "unfollowed": False,
            "scraped": False,
            "pm_sent": False,
        }
    },
    {
        "updated_data": {
            "last_interaction": "2023-06-20 06:55:55.652434",
            "following_status": "followed",
            "session_id": 123,
            "type": "update",
            "job_name": "blogger-following",
            "target": "name5",
            "liked": 21,
            "watched": 790,
            "commented": 0,
            "followed": False,
            "unfollowed": False,
            "scraped": False,
            "pm_sent": False,
        }
    },
]
```

Comment: if more than 2  same session Ids then i need to consider latest "last_interaction"

Comment: if morethan 2 same session ids then i need to consider type="update" and max(last_interaction) to take latest one

Comment: i have updated my json in question.. 3 session ids have same session_ids but last session id has last transaction on 2023.. but it yielding 2022 one in output with your latest code. please check.. i need to conside max i.e latest transaction

Comment: @ditil With your updated data the output for `session_id==123` is the date `2023-06-20 06:55:55.652434`

Comment: so  reverse=True gives me latest transaction then...am i right ?

Comment: @ditil Yes, the reverse True will get the latest transaction (sorting from most new to oldest).